# Java: How to create a vector lookup table to find object instances of parsed cartesian vector points

Tags: java

I'm making a chess game and i am handling the direction in which pieces moves with "unit vectors".

For example. A pawn will generally have a unit vector of (0,1) as it can only move one space forward.

Because of this I am creating many instances that hold the same data. To prevent this and to prevent the wastage of system resources, i decide to hold a central lookup table to hold a list of all the position vectors that can be used on a board (9x9)

What would the best way to go about this be? Because I can't just have a Set of these vectors and find the one which has the same parsed cartesian points without a iteration, which i'd like to avoid

Answer (score 1):

First, remember...

> "We should forget about small efficiencies, say about 97% of the time: premature optimization is the root of all evil."

Thus, it would be prudent to design your Movement Vector class in such a way that *permits* this optimization, but delay actually implementing it until things are fairly functional.

That said, it's not all that hard to do (and thorough Unit Testing can ensure that your optimization doesn't introduce any bugs). The easiest way is to use either a `Map<Integer, Map<Integer, A>>` or `Map<String, A>`, where `A` is your movement vector class. You could implement it as such:

```
public class MovementVector {

    private static Map<String, MovementVector> cache = new HashMap<>();

    //Step 0 : all fields must be immutable, or instance sharing will backfire catastrophically
    public final int r;
    public final int c;

    //Step 1 : make constructor(s) private so new instances can't be created without your knowledge
    private MovementVector(int r, int c) {
        this.r = r;
        this.c = c;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return makeString(r, c);
    }

    //Step 2 : single method that makes keys for a given r,c.
    // Must be static so it can be used in get(..) below.
    private static String makeString(int r, int c) {
        return "(" + r + "," + c + ")";
    }

    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (! (o instanceof MovementVector)) return false;
        MovementVector m = (MovementVector)o;
        return r == m.r && c == m.c;
    }

    public int hashCode() {
        return r * 10 + c;
    }

    //Step 3 : public static getter that functions as constructor/instance retriever
    public static MovementVector get(int r, int c) {
        String str = makeString(r,c);
        MovementVector vectorFromCache = cache.get(str);
        if (vectorFromCache != null) return vectorFromCache;
        else {
            MovementVector v = new MovementVector(r,c);
            cache.put(str, v); 
            return v;
        }
    }
}
```

And the usage:

```
MovementVector pawnMovement = MovementVector.get(0,1);
MovementVector pawnMovement2 = MovementVector.get(0,1);
//pawnMovement == pawnMovement2
```